# Wordpress get_posts() offset by finding index of post by slug

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a Wordpress page which aggregates all posts of a type (press-post).

I want to be able to pass in a URL parameter of a post, which will offset the query to start at the index of the post slug.

For example, `www.mysite.com/press` should start at offset 0, where as `www.mysite.com/press?post=third-post-slug` should query at offset 2.

How can I find the offset of a post in a query by its slug?

Here is my code so far:

```
if ($_GET['post']):
    $post_offset = // Here I need to get the offset of that post in the query;
  else:
    $post_offset = 0;
  endif;

  $args = array(
    'post_type'       => 'press',
    'post_status'     => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'  => 15,
    'offset'          => $post_offset,
    'paged'           => $page_no,
    'orderby'         => 'date',
    'order'           => 'DESC',
  );

  $press_posts = get_posts($args);
```

Comment: get all the posts loop through them with a counter. When you get to the slug you want break the loop and use the count value for the offset.

Comment: I thought of that, but potentially it's going to be a bit slow? It's not likely that there'll be 1000's of posts though. What do you think...

Comment: yes it is, but im not sure how else you would do it. A quicker approach might be to query the DB yourself. But WP DB is a bit of a mess.

Answer (score 0):

Delayed response here... in case anyone else is trying to get the current post's offset, this will do the job. This was helpful when trying to display subsequent podcast episodes for a "podcast" CPT.

```
  // get 'em all
  $allPosts = get_posts([
    'post_type' => get_post_type($post_id),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'fields' => 'ids'
  ]);
  // loop through all posts to get current post index
  if(!empty($allPosts)) {
    $n = 0;
    foreach($allPosts as $ap) {
      if($ap == $post_id) {
        $currentPostOffset = $n;
        continue;
      }
      $n++;
    }
  }
  // here's your query with subsequent post offset
  $numPosts = 3;
  $relatedPosts = get_posts([
    'post_type' => get_post_type($post_id),
    'posts_per_page' => $numPosts,
    'offset' => $currentPostOffset,
    'post__not_in' => [$post_id],
    'fields' => 'ids' // optional - you can grab the whole post object here if you like
  ]);
  // I always want to show 3 posts. When we're showing the last few posts there are less than 3 subsequent posts, so go back to the top and make up for the difference
  if(count($relatedPosts) < $numPosts) {
    $numPostsToAdd = $numPosts - count($relatedPosts);
    $postsToAdd = get_posts([
      'post_type' => get_post_type($post_id),
      'posts_per_page' => $numPostsToAdd,
      'post__not_in' => [$post_id],
      'fields' => 'ids'
    ]);
    if(!empty($postsToAdd)) {
      foreach($postsToAdd as $pta) {
        array_push($relatedPosts, $pta);
      }
    }
  }
```